# Three.js BufferedGeometry VertexColors

Tags: three.js

https://jsfiddle.net/Mihails/uko6dzwj

```
   var colors = new Float32Array([
   // All Ok with green color:
    0, 250, 0,
    0, 250, 0,
    0, 250, 0,

   // Issue is here. Why color is not magenta?
    249,149,249,
    249,149,249,
    249,149,249,
  ]);
```

Scene has BufferedGeometry (plane in the middle has 2 triangles):

- First triangle has green color (0, 250, 0) - all ok
- Second triangle expected to be magenta (see line Line #74: color is 249,149,249)

Why second triangle has a wrong color? Where I did a mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Colors take values in the range [ 0, 1 ] in three.js -- not [ 0, 255 ].

three.js r.77